# Find a basis for the image and kernel of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I'm having a bit of difficulty obtaining an answer to this problem. Specifically, finding a basis for the kernel of a transformation, $\ker(T)$ .

> Let \begin{align*}
> p_1(t)&=-1+t \\ 
> p_2(t)&=-t+t^2 \\
> p_3(t)&=-1+t^3, \quad\text{and}\\
> p_4(t)&=2t-t^2-t^3.
> \end{align*} Let $W=\operatorname{span}\{p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4\}$, a subspace of $\mathbf P_3$.
>
> Let $T: W \to \mathbf P_2$ be a linear transformation so that $T(p_i) = q_i$ where 
>   \begin{align*}
> q_1(t)&=-1+t+t^2 \\
> q_2(t)&=2+4t-t^2 \\
> q_3(t)&=1+11t+t^2 \quad\text{and}\\
> q_4(t)&= -4-14t+t^2.
> \end{align*}
>
> 1. Find a basis for $\operatorname{im}(T)$. The elements of this basis must be polynomials in $\mathbf P_2$.
> 2. Find a basis for $\ker(T)$. The elements of this basis must be polynomials in $W$.

I've been able to find (1) by taking the image of each element in $W$ (given by $q_1...q_4$) putting them into a matrix and row reducing to find the column space. Here I know that $\{q_1,q_2\}$ form a basis for $\operatorname{im}(T)$.

However I'm having trouble with finding $\ker(T)$. I believe the next step is to find the null space of the matrix with vector columns of $q_1 \ldots q_4$, but I am not sure of this. The answer given is $g=-3p_1-2p_2+p_3$. This seems to come about if I find the null space of a matrix with columns $q_1 \ldots q_3$, but what about $q_4$? I am likely misunderstanding something here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this is the best way to do this, but I tried to determine $T$ from the given data points $T(p_i) = q_i$.

I got the matrix (see appendix)
$$
T =
\begin{pmatrix}
a-1  & a-2  & a   & a \\
b-11 & b-10 & b-6 & b \\
c-1  & c    & c-1 & c \\
d    & d    & d   & d
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $a,b,c,d$ are free variables. So we have many candidates for $T$.

Solving for $T x = 0$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a-1  & a-2  & a   & a \\
b-11 & b-10 & b-6 & b \\
c-1  & c    & c-1 & c \\
d    & d    & d   & d
\end{pmatrix}
\to
\begin{pmatrix}
a-1  & a-2  & a   & a \\
b-11 & b-10 & b-6 & b \\
c-1  & c    & c-1 & c \\
1    & 1    & 1   & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\to
\\
\begin{pmatrix}
a & a-1 & a+1 & a+1 \\
b & b+1 & b+5 & b+11 \\
c & c+1 & c   & c+1 \\
1 & 1   & 1   & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\to
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 & 1 &  1 \\
0 &  1 & 5 & 11 \\
0 &  1 & 0 &  1 \\
1 &  1 & 1 &  1
\end{pmatrix}
\to
\\
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 &  2 \\
0 & 0 & 5 & 10 \\
0 & 1 & 0 &  1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 &  0
\end{pmatrix}
\to
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 &  0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 &  2 \\
0 & 1 & 0 &  1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & -2
\end{pmatrix}
\to
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & -2 \\
0 & 1 & 0 &  1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 &  2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 &  0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
This gives the solutions $x = (2s, -s, -2s, s)^\top = s (2,-1,-2,1)^\top = s (2 -t -2 t^2 + t^3)$ for $s \in \mathbb{R}$, thus $\ker T$ is created by one basis vector, which agrees with your solution.

**Determining $T$**

We know $Q = T P$ with

```
P =

  -1   0  -1   0
   1  -1   0   2
   0   1   0  -1
   0   0   1  -1

Q =

   -1    2    1   -4
    1    4   11  -14
    1   -1    1    1
    0    0    0    0
```

and then linearize $T$ into $x = (t_{11}, t_{12}, t_{13}, t_{14}, t_{21}, \dotsc, t_{44})^\top$ to get a system $A x = b$ with

```
A =

  -1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0  -1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  -1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   2  -1  -1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0  -1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0  -1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0  -1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   2  -1  -1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  -1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  -1   1   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  -1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2  -1  -1   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  -1   1   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  -1   1   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  -1   0   0   1
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2  -1  -1
```

and

```
b =

   -1
    2
    1
   -4
    1
    4
   11
  -14
    1
   -1
    1
    1
    0
    0
    0
    0
```

Then Gauss-Jordan elimination gives the row-echelon form:

```
>> rref([A,b])
ans =

 Columns 1 through 15:

    1    0    0   -1   -0   -0   -0   -0   -0   -0   -0   -0   -0   -0   -0
    0    1    0   -1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
    0    0    1   -1   -0   -0   -0   -0   -0   -0   -0   -0   -0   -0   -0
    0    0    0    0    1    0    0   -1   -0   -0   -0   -0   -0   -0   -0
    0    0    0    0    0    1    0   -1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
    0    0    0    0    0    0    1   -1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0   -1   -0   -0   -0
    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0   -1    0    0    0
    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1   -1    0    0    0
    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

and

```
 Columns 16 and 17:

   -0   -1
    0   -2
   -0   -0
   -0  -11
    0  -10
    0   -6
   -0   -1
    0    0
    0   -1
   -1   -0
   -1    0
   -1    0
    0    0
    0    0
    0    0
    0    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the columns of 
$$
A=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
-1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1
\end{array}\right]
$$
are identified with the polynomials $p_1$, $p_2$, $p_3$, and $p_4$. Row reducing gives
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}\rref A=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
This tells us that $W$ is three-dimensional with basis $\{p_1,p_2,p_3\}$.

Now, note that the columns of 
$$
B=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
-1 & 2 & 1 & -4 \\
1 & 4 & 11 & -14 \\
1 & -1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$
are identified with the polynomials $q_1$, $q_2$, $q_3$, and $q_4$. Row reducing gives
$$
\rref B=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 0 & 3 & -2 \\
0 & 1 & 2 & -3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
This tells us that the image of $T$ is two-dimensional with basis $\{q_1,q_2\}$.

The rank-nullity theorem then implies that $\ker T$ is one-dimensional. To find a basis for $\ker T$, note that $\rref B$ tells us that the vector 
$$
\vec v=\left(1,\,4,\,1,\,2\right)
$$
is in the null space of $B$. This tells us that
$$
q_1+4\,q_2+q_3+2\,q_4=0
$$
It follows that
$$
T(p_1)+4\,T(p_2)+T(p_3)+2\,T(p_4)=0
$$
so that
$$
T(p_1+4\,p_2+p_3+2\,p_4)=0
$$
That is, the polynomial
$$
p_1+4\,p_2+p_3+2\,p_4=-t^3+2\,t^2+t-2
$$
forms a basis for $\ker T$.

Comment: You appear to have an error in rref $A$—the upper-right element should be $-1$.

Comment: @amd Nope. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=rref+%7B%7B-1,0,-1,0%7D,%7B1,-1,0,2%7D,%7B0,1,0,-1%7D,%7B0,0,1,-1%7D%7D

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick - this explanation is very thorough but I get lost when you find the basis for ker$T$. I'd find a basis for ker$T$ by finding a basis for the null space of rref$B$ which gives me a basis $\{(-3,-2,1,0),(2,3,0,1)\}$. I understand why ker$T$ should really be one dimensional, but the basis I'm finding (incorrectly) has two vectors. How did you find  $\vec{v}=(1,4,1,2)$?

Comment: nm. I had transposed two elements of the original matrix.

Comment: @econom I’m not sure where $(1,4,1,2)$ came from, but you can work with the two kernel vectors that you’ve found. They describe linear combinations of the $p$’s and you’ll find that when you expand and simplify them (equivalently, multiply those two vectors by $A$), you end up with the same polynomial. You could also have worked with just $q_1$ through $q_3$ to find the image and kernel since rref $A$ shows that $p_4$ is redundant. (Retaining the latter in the computations checks that $T$ is indeed linear, so it’s not completely wasted.)